# Getting an issue cannot import name 'TouchActions' from 'selenium.webdriver'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an Error while  importing below modules in my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

import undetected_chromedriver as uc
```

Error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'TouchActions' from 'selenium.webdriver'`

Can somebody please help.

Thanks!

I tried to reinstall selenium. But didn't work